# HTML Input doesn't allow double digits to be typed in from keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a [basic calculator](https://harrisj09.github.io/The-Unconventional-Calculator/) and so far it "works". Users can only enter in a single digit from their keyboard. If they want to use double digits they're going to have to use the arrows in the text box. How can I make it so that users can enter in double digit numbers? If the user tries to type in double digit numbers the second number only get stored (so typing in 25 will only store 5)

```js
// Base Variables
let result = 0;
let numb1 = 0;
let numb2 = 0;
let firstNumberEntered = false;

//This will be rewritten
let calculationDescription = `${numb1} + ${numb2}`;

document.querySelector('#input-number').addEventListener('keypress', numbersInput);

function numbersInput(e) {
  if (!firstNumberEntered && e.key === 'Enter') {
    numb1 = document.getElementById("input-number").value;
    firstNumberEntered = true;
    document.getElementById("input-number").innerHTML = "";
  } else if (firstNumberEntered && e.key === 'Enter') {
    numb2 = document.getElementById("input-number").value;
    firstNumberEntered = false;
    console.log(`${numb1} and ${numb2}`);
  }
  document.getElementById("input-number").value = "";
}

document.querySelector("#btn-add").addEventListener('click', sumNumbs);
document.querySelector("#btn-subtract").addEventListener('click', subtractNumbs);
document.querySelector("#btn-multiply").addEventListener('click', multiplyNumbs);
document.querySelector("#btn-divide").addEventListener('click', divideNumbs);

function sumNumbs() {
  let numb1Final = parseInt(numb1);
  let numb2Final = parseInt(numb2);
  result = numb1Final + numb2Final;
  calculationDescription = `${numb1} + ${numb2}`;
  outputResult(result, calculationDescription);
}

function subtractNumbs() {
  let numb1Final = parseInt(numb1);
  let numb2Final = parseInt(numb2);
  result = numb1Final - numb2Final;
  calculationDescription = `${numb1} - ${numb2}`;
  outputResult(result, calculationDescription);
}

function multiplyNumbs() {
  let numb1Final = parseInt(numb1);
  let numb2Final = parseInt(numb2);
  result = numb1Final * numb2Final;
  calculationDescription = `${numb1} x ${numb2}`;
  outputResult(result, calculationDescription);
}

function divideNumbs() {
  let numb1Final = parseInt(numb1);
  let numb2Final = parseInt(numb2);
  result = numb1Final / numb2Final;
  calculationDescription = `${numb1} / ${numb2}`;
  outputResult(result, calculationDescription);
}
```

```html
<section id="calculator">
  <input type="number" id="input-number" />
  <div id="calc-actions">
    <button type="button" id="btn-add">+</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn-subtract">-</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn-multiply">*</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn-divide">/</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

All this does is grab the elements on the HTML page and put them into variables and send info back to be displayed

```js
const userInput = document.getElementById('input-number');
const addBtn = document.getElementById('btn-add');
const subtractBtn = document.getElementById('btn-subtract');
const multiplyBtn = document.getElementById('btn-multiply');
const divideBtn = document.getElementById('btn-divide');

const currentResultOutput = document.getElementById('current-result');
const currentCalculationOutput = document.getElementById('current-calculation');

function outputResult(result, text) {
  currentResultOutput.textContent = result;
  currentCalculationOutput.textContent = text;
}
```

**Not sure if providing my CSS is necessary, but let me know and I'll make a change.**

I just started learning JavaScript recently. I watched a few videos on a Udemy tutorial on doing this project, but I stopped watching and tried to figure the rest out myself.

What I did try doing was adding `maxlength="6"` to my HTML input element, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function numbersInput(e) {
    if(!firstNumberEntered && e.key === 'Enter') {
        numb1 = document.getElementById("input-number").value;
        firstNumberEntered = true;
        document.getElementById("input-number").innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById("input-number").value = "";
    }
    else if(firstNumberEntered && e.key === 'Enter') {
        numb2 = document.getElementById("input-number").value;
        firstNumberEntered = false;
        console.log(`${numb1} and ${numb2}`);
    document.getElementById("input-number").value = "";

    }

}
```

Add `document.getElementById("input-number").value = "";`
 to the end of both if statements and remove from the end of the function

Comment: Thanks it works now. Could you explain to me why this fixes it?

Comment: Because you were clearing the input on every key press. So everytime you pressed a key this line ran `document.getElementById("input-number").value = "";` which effectively removed what ever was in the input box previously.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my own **basic calculator using HTML, CSS, and javascript only**.
To be able to input one or more digit numbers, use arrays to function as storage of those numbers chosen and for your chosen arithmetic operation as well.
please see my source code for a clearer grasp of my idea.

```
//index.html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>My HTML/CSS/JS Calculator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="outer-container">
            <div class="items" id="items"></div>
            <div class="calc-screen">
                <div id="screen"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="keys-container">
                <button type="button" class="keys" id="opm" onclick="opm()">*</button>
                <button type="button" class="keys" id="opd" onclick="opd()">/</button>
                <button type="button" class="keys" id="opa" onclick="opa()">+</button>
                <button type="button" class="keys" id="ops" onclick="ops()">-</button>
    
                <button type="button" class="keys" id="num9" onclick="num9()">9</button>
                <button type="button" class="keys" id="num8" onclick="num8()">8</button>
                <button type="button" class="keys" id="num7" onclick="num7()">7</button>
                <button type="button" class="keys" id="num6" onclick="num6()">6</button>
    
                <button type="button" class="keys" id="num5" onclick="num5()">5</button>
                <button type="button" class="keys" id="num4" onclick="num4()">4</button>
                <button type="button" class="keys" id="num3" onclick="num3()">3</button>
                <button type="button" class="keys" id="num2" onclick="num2()">2</button>
    
                <button type="button" class="keys" id="num1" onclick="num1()">1</button>
                <button type="button" class="keys" id="num0" onclick="num0()">0</button>
                <button type="button" class="keys" id="del" onclick="del()">Del</button>
                <button type="button" class="keys" id="clr" onclick="clr()">Clr</button>
    
                <button type="submit" class="keys" id="equals" onclick='equals()'>=</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
    
//js.js
    var item1, op, item2, arr1, arr2, text, x, prod, qout, sum, diff, a, b, c;
    item1, item2, op = '';
    arr1 = [];
    arr2 = [];
    
    function num9() {
        if (op=='') {
            arr1.push(document.getElementById("num9").innerHTML);
            arr1Function();
        }
        else {
            arr2.push(document.getElementById("num9").innerHTML);
            arr2Function();
        }
    }
    function num8() {
        if (op=='') {
            arr1.push(document.getElementById("num8").innerHTML);
            arr1Function();
        }
        else {
            arr2.push(document.getElementById("num8").innerHTML);
            arr2Function();
        }
    }
    function num7() {
        if (op=='') {
            arr1.push(document.getElementById("num7").innerHTML);
            arr1Function();
        }
        else {
            arr2.push(document.getElementById("num7").innerHTML);
            arr2Function();
        }
    }
    function num6() {
        if (op=='') {
            arr1.push(document.getElementById("num6").innerHTML);
            arr1Function();
        }
        else {
            arr2.push(document.getElementById("num6").innerHTML);
            arr2Function();
        }
    }
    function num5() {
        if (op=='') {
            arr1.push(document.getElementById("num5").innerHTML);
            arr1Function();
        }
        else {
            arr2.push(document.getElementById("num5").innerHTML);
            arr2Function();
        }
    }
    function num4() {
        if (op=='') {
            arr1.push(document.getElementById("num4").innerHTML);
            arr1Function();
        }
        else {
            arr2.push(document.getElementById("num4").innerHTML);
            arr2Function();
        }
    }
    function num3() {
        if (op=='') {
            arr1.push(document.getElementById("num3").innerHTML);
            arr1Function();
        }
        else {
            arr2.push(document.getElementById("num3").innerHTML);
            arr2Function();
        }
    }
    function num2() {
        if (op=='') {
            arr1.push(document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML);
            arr1Function();
        }
        else {
            arr2.push(document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML);
            arr2Function();
        }
    }
    function num1() {
        if (op=='') {
            arr1.push(document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML);
            arr1Function();
        }
        else {
            arr2.push(document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML);
            arr2Function();
        }
    }
    function num0() {
        if (op=='') {
            arr1.push(document.getElementById("num0").innerHTML);
            arr1Function();
        }
        else {
            arr2.push(document.getElementById("num0").innerHTML);
            arr2Function();
        }
    }
    
    function opm() {
        if (arr1=='') {
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = "Please press a number first!";
        }
        else if (op!='' && arr2!='') {
            console.log("press equal sign");
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = document.getElementById("opm").innerHTML;
            op = '*';
            console.log(op);
        }
    }
    function opd() {
        if (arr1=='') {
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = "Please press a number first!";
        }
        else if (op!='' && arr2!='') {
            console.log("press equal sign");
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = document.getElementById("opd").innerHTML;
            op = '/';
            console.log(op);
        }
    }
    function opa() {
        if (arr1=='') {
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = "Please press a number first!";
        }
        else if (op!='' && arr2!='') {
            console.log("press equal sign");
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = document.getElementById("opa").innerHTML;
            op = '+';
            console.log(op);
        }
    }
    function ops() {
        if (arr1=='') {
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = "Please press a number first!";
        }
        else if (op!='' && arr2!='') {
            console.log("press equal sign");
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = document.getElementById("ops").innerHTML;
            op = '-';
            console.log(op);
        }
    }
    
    function equals() {
        a = parseInt(item1); b = parseInt(item2);
        if (op == '*') {
            prod = a * b;
            document.getElementById("items").innerHTML = a+' '+op+' '+b+' =';
            c = prod;
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = c;
            console.log('product: '+c);
            result(c);
        }
        else if (op == '/') {
            qout = a / b;
            document.getElementById("items").innerHTML = a+' '+op+' '+b+' =';
            c = qout;
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = c;
            console.log('qoutient: '+c);
            result(c);
        }
        else if (op == '+') {
            sum = a + b;
            document.getElementById("items").innerHTML = a+' '+op+' '+b+' =';
            c = sum;
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = c;
            console.log('sum: '+c);     
            result(c);
        }
        else if (op == '-') {
            diff = a - b;
            document.getElementById("items").innerHTML = a+' '+op+' '+b+ ' =';
            c = diff;
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = c;
            console.log('difference: '+c);  
            result(c);  
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = "Please press a number first!";
        }
    }
    
    function result() {
        console.log('function result: '+c);
        arr1=[]; arr2=[]; item1, item2, op = '';
        item1 = c;
        console.log('function result new item1: '+item1);
        arr1.push(item1);
        arr1Function();
    }
    
    function del() {
        if (arr1!='' && op=='' && arr2=='') {
            arr1.pop();
            console.log(arr1);
            arr1Function();
        }
        else if (arr1!='' && op!='' && arr2=='') {
            op = '';
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = op;
        }
        else if (arr1!='' && op!='' && arr2!='') {
            arr2.pop();
            console.log(arr2);
            arr2Function();
        }
    }
    
    function clr() {
        arr1=[]; arr2=[]; item1,item2,op='';
        console.log(arr1+', '+op+', '+arr2+', '+item1+', '+item2); 
        document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById("items").innerHTML = '';
    }
    
    function arr1Function() {
        document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = arr1;
        text = ""; arr1.forEach(myFunction); text += "";
        function myFunction(value) {
            text += value;
            x = parseInt(text);
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = x;
            item1 = x;
            console.log("Arr 1 Parse: "+x);
            console.log("Arr 1: "+arr1);
            console.log("Item 1: "+item1);
        }
    }
    
    function arr2Function() {
        document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = arr2;
        text = ""; arr2.forEach(myFunction); text += "";
        function myFunction(value) {
            text += value;
            x = parseInt(text);
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = x;
            item2 = x;
            console.log("Arr 2 Parse: "+x);
            console.log("Arr 2: "+arr2);
            console.log("Item 2: "+item2);
        }
    }
    
//css
    body {
        background-color: orange;
    }
    
    .outer-container {
        position: static;
        background-color: black;
        margin: auto;
        border: solid black 2px;
        width: 350px;
        padding: 20px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    
    .items {
        background-color: silver;
        border: solid white 1px;
        display: inline-block;
        color: black;
        max-width: 100%;
        font-size: 16px;
        height: 20px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .calc-screen {
        padding: 10px;
        border: solid white 1px;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: silver;
        color: white;
        font-size: 25px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow-x: auto;
    }
    
    .keys-container {
        margin-top: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        border: solid white 1px;
        max-width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    #equals {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .keys {
        float: left;
        border: solid black 1px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 25%;
        height: 40px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
        font-size: 25px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    
    .keys:hover {
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
    }
```